# Error loading external javascript files in jade layout in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I'm new at Angularjs and just want to load some external js files to work in my app (they're big so I don't want to put them directly into the controller).

I tried to use

```
ng-include(src='javascripts/javascriptfile.js')
```

But I get these error messages

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token 'js' is an unexpected token at column 28 of the expression [javascripts/javascriptfile.js] starting at [js].

TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The problem is, it works when I was using these files in express with no error messages, so I know it's not the javascript file, and when I try to use things like

```
(script src= 'javascripts/javascriptfile.js')
```

without the ng-include, nothing executes.

Answer (score 0):

ng-include is for including HTML template partials, not javascript.

You should use the <script> tag to include javascript files.

Comment: So how should I add the scripts to the page?
I put them in the head of layout.jade

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
script(src='javascripts/javascriptfile.js')
```

instead of:

```
(script src= 'javascripts/javascriptfile.js')
```